# Is there a way to obtain index in array in more concise way?

Tags: javascript

Curiosity only sponsors this question, as it's always fun to hack in languages.

Assume that there is an array holding objects of some kind. Objects have an id property. Id cannot be empty string, false, null or any falsey value. Array can be of zero length. I want to obtain index of this value (if present) and exit the loop as soon as it's found.

```
var id = /some value to check/;
var index;
for (var i = 0, item; item = arr[i], 
     item===undefined?false:item.id==id?(index=i,false):true; i++);
```

What do you think?

Comment: The code is "too clever" and might be more clear (without being more verbose) to write it as a loop with a body using a `break`. In the real world, I would normally use a higher-order / existing function in most cases - as this adds 'conciseness' without losing clarity.

Comment: I think this belongs at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2864740 - I'm perfectly aware that it could be more verbose. It actually can be written in lots of ways. But I'm curious if could be more concise. Wouldn't however use break - it's "dirty" way of breaking the loop. Normally would just put checks in body of loop.

Comment: @mplungjan - I suppose it belongs here better, as code review deals more with practical code, not such theoretical questions. This code is far from being of practical use in maintainable code...

Comment: Writing it "less clever" does not mean it has to be more verbose: `var i = 0; for(; arr[i]; i++) if (arr[i].id == id) break;` -- now use `arr[i]` (will be the object if found, undefined otherwise). I prefer to pull variables (eg. `i`) out of the loop to imply scope intent, even if hoisting makes it irrelevant. I would also include relevant new lines / indents / braces.

Comment: @user2864740 This way is more concise, however I don't like breaks (old habit from even older times). But this can be done without break with while. So: `var i=arr.length; while (i && arr[i-1].id!=id) {i--}`. Then `i` holds the value after. Hope not messed something.

Comment: `const value = array.find(item => !!item);` ... or `(item => item && item.id === id)`, I don't understand what's your problem here.

Comment: @Azamantes - agreed, but won't work in IE. So not universal. I like ES5&6&7 thingies, but still mostly, without stress, can use it in node only.
Besides - there is no problem at all, just conversation about different solutions. See my introductory post - I mentioned curiosity.

Comment: What do you mean 'won't work', just change const to var and arrow function to the normal one. Cool, I too often wonder how to improve my code.

Comment: @Azamantes If I change it in your code, get rid of find (which isn't in IE), it would no longer be concise.
Besides I have reasons to believe that arrow functions and find are far slower than for and while loops. When will have some time will get outcome of this discuss and make jsperf test case.

Comment: @Azamantes - while not direct comparison this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/function-vs-arrow-function) shows terrible difference in arrow functions performance versus normal functions in FF and almost equal in Chrome. As functions are inherently slower than loops I can safely assume that loops based solution will be lot faster. But will check it.

Comment: If things like this concern you, you might want to switch to assembly already. Unless you run this piece of code very frequently and you find it a bottleneck, the performance differences are negligible. Also this jsperf example is stupid, nobody sane creates a new function inside loop iteration. It should be cached and tested that way against normal loop. You can create your own version of 'find' method and use that instead in IE.

Comment: I'm concerned about performance, because I use JS not only for web. If one deals with games or complex large datasets things become less negligible . I don't have to switch, I did assembly already. And I cannot use it in browsers. 
As to jsperf - this was first I found and run. It isn't stupid - there are situations when perfectly sane people create functions inside loops. Because sometimes it's needed for some specific purpose. Like factory things or alike.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I did jsperf with posted above suggestions. Please play around if you want.

[jsperf mentioned](https://jsperf.com/concise-loops)

Fastest are my initial example above under FF and my `while` loop posted in comments under Chrome. `find` solution with arrow functions is slowest in both cases. Cannot test in IE as I use no Win.

I'm aware this jsperf is badly written - please play around.

Comment: Your question refers to "conciseness", yet this "answer" focuses on performance. Which is it that you are interested in?

Comment: @torazaburo Both. While looking for concise way happened to find some auxiliary drawbacks/benefits. That's all.
But question was about conciseness - do you have some proposal of solution maybe?